# Accessing Object Attributes within Symfony Forms

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony4

I am trying to display a list of courses with a checkbox allowing the user to select any number of courses from the list. I am new to Symfony and trying to follow the form approach but do not understand how to display additional attributes of an object beyond using the choice_label.

If I were just passing the course objects, I could simply use:

Template:

```
<form>
    {% for course in courses %}
        <div class="row">
            <div><input type="checkbox" name="course[]" value="{{ course.id }}"></div>
            <div>{{ course.name }}</div>
            <div>{{ course.description }}</div>
            <div>{{ course.semester }}</div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Using the form builder, it seems my template would look like this:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
        <div class="row">
            <div>{{ form_row(form.courses) }}</div>
        </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

How can I access these additional object attributes (name, description, etc.) within the form row? Is there a reason to use to the form builder in this case instead of the first 'by hand' approach? In summary, I need granular control of the object attributes within a given form row and the choice_label attribute alone does not seem sufficient. What is a potential solution?

Answer (score 1):

First, for accessing each option of the choice label, it's fairly simple... because *the form.courses is an array*.
You can access individual checkbox by doing this :

```
{{ form_widget(form.courses[0]) }}
```

And you can use a loop to access them individually. And for customizing the rendering of your forms, you can use **form_errors**, **form_label** and **form_help** functions, so your final code will be something like this :

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {% for course in form.courses %}
        <div class="row">
            {{ form_widget(course) }}
            {{ form_label(course) }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {{ form_help(form.courses) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

**Note:** The label is the key value in the array passed to the « choices » option in Form Builder.

**Sources:**

How to Customize Form Rendering : https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have read through that documentation and understand the usage of label. However, the issue is that I want to display 5 or so attributes associated with the object  (such as name, description, semester, etc) not just a single label. It does not seem that the form component can accept custom attributes as far as I can tell?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't. You have to put everything in the label or treat every checkbox separately. And it only accepts widget-wide help. You can also, instead of using ChoiceType + multiple=true, using multiple CheckboxeTypes + multiple=false. I don't know if i'm clear enough.